# Google App Engine: Entity ID not showing

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this in the Google App Engine python code,

```
class ABC(db.Model):
  StringA = db.StringProperty()

abcs = ABC.all()
template_values = {'abcs': abcs,}
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

and this in the index.html,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{% for abc in abcs %}
  var id = "{{ abc.ID }}"; // needed the entity ID, the abc.ID doesn't show??
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

What was the right keyword to use for the entity ID, the abc.ID??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{abc.key.id}}`, assuming you're using Django templates.  The ID isn't a property of the object, it's a part of the object's Key; in a Django template (which is what you're using if you're using google.appengine.ext.webapp.template), this is the equivalent to `abc.key().id()` in Python code.

Note that not all entities have an ID at all; they could have a key name instead if you've set one.